# Merge 4 NICs in one / Technical Name

Tags: linux, networking, installation, centos

**Hi every one** 
on a web server running Centos 6 with 4 Network Interfaces, we have to setup/Merge all 4 interfaces to be shown / used as a single NIC, we know it's possible but we forgot the technical name of the solution, we need just the name to google it if it's possible.

Thanks

Comment: Bonding or teaming. Depending on O/S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word your looking for is "bonding".  That's what it's called in Linux.

Comment: just for info, a usful link to setup Bonding under centos/RHEL 6.X
http://www.tokiwinter.com/configuring-interface-bonding-on-centosrheloel-6-x/